# Python server daemon not working

Tags: python, sockets, server, daemon

I need to make a basic python server run as a daemon but when I set the thread to run as a daemon, the socket doesnt listen anymore. I try to connect to it with a client to send a file to it but I get a connection error. When I leave out the part that sets it to a daemon, it works just fine. Suggestions? Thanks

Server code:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 3000
exit = False

def handle_client(client):
    global exit
    filename = client.recv(50).decode()
    client.send(b"/ok")

    if filename == '':
        client.close()

        return
    elif filename == '/kill':
        exit = True
        client.send(b'killing server...\n')

        killserver = socket.socket()
        killserver.connect((HOST, PORT))
        killserver.close()

        client.send(b'success.\n')
        client.close()

        return

    f = open(filename, "wb")

    data = client.recv(1024)
    while(data):
        f.write(data)
        data = client.recv(1024)
    f.close()

    print("Wrote file " + filename)

    client.close()

def server():
    servsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    servsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    servsock.bind((HOST,PORT))

    print("[INFO]: listening on " + str(PORT))
    servsock.listen(10)

    while True:
        client, addr = servsock.accept()

        if exit is True:
            print("[INFO]: server received kill request")
            break

        print("[INFO]: connection from " + addr[0])

        hc = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
        hc.start()

    servsock.close()

s = threading.Thread(target=server)
s.setDaemon(True)
s.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are only daemon threads running, the process exits. After you start the thread, you exit the main thread.  You don't want the server thread to be daemonic.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way I can get the server to run in the background like a regular daemon?

Comment: That depends on your OS.  On Windows, running Pythonw.exe will create the process without a console.

Comment: Im running Linux. Im planning on moving this to an Ubuntu Server, so I'd like to run it from the command line and leave it in the background so I can run multiple programs.

Comment: Just run the process in the background. Isn't it just adding & to the command?